# Upper bound for a summatory function

Tags: number-theory

Let $\pi(N)$ denote the number of primes $\le N$, and $\Omega(n)$ the number of prime divisors of $n$, counting multiplicity.

I derived the inequality $\pi(N)\le 1/2+\sum^N_{n=2}1/\Omega(n)$ for $N\ge2$ and is wondering whether there is a nice upper bound for the sum, so that when both sides are divided by $N$ we can show that the density of the primes is $0$ by taking $N\to\infty$.

I realized that $\sum^N_{n=2}1/\Omega(n)$ is a sum of reciprocals, but using the generalized mean inequality gives

$$
\sum^N_{n=2}\frac{1}{\Omega(n)}\le \sqrt {N-1}\left(\sum^N_{n=2}\frac{1}{\Omega(n)^2}\right)^{1/2},
$$

which does not simplify the matter.

Comment: Help people understand your question better. Define $\Pi$ and $\Omega$.

Comment: @Medo Thanks for your suggestion.